# Drifblim's Explosion attack in Pokémon

Tags: anime, pokemon

Since Explosion is a Normal-type move, it means that Ghost-type Pokémon are immune to it (see [here](https://www.math.miami.edu/%7Ejam/azure/attacks/e/explosion.htm#:%7E:text=Because%20it%20is%20a%20Normal,Yellow%2C%20this%20is%20not%20true.) for this information), even if, I would think, they initially employed the attack in battle. Does this mean that Ghost-type Pokémon like Drifblim are immune to their own Explosions, making it overpowered in a Pokémon battle? I am mainly referring to the anime but the same question can be asked of the video games.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this mean that Ghost-type Pokémon like Drifblim are immune to their own Explosions...?

**No.** If a Ghost-type Pokémon uses Explosion, it will faint like any other Pokémon. The "user faints" side-effect bypasses the damage system and, as part of that, bypasses the type chart. The same is true of Self-Destruct (a slightly weaker move with the same effect).

I can't find a clip of Drifblim using Explosion in the anime, but in the following clip from *Pokémon Battle Revolution*, you can see a Drifblim using Explosion and fainting as a result. The other Drifblim on the field *is* immune to the damage dealt by the move, however.